# Opacity of a custom UIButton

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

By default, we get the opacity of UIButton set to NO. Can we set it to YES?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Um... `opacity` is not a boolean value.  It is a `float` in the range from 0.0 (fully transparent) to 1.0 (fully opaque).  The property is actually called the `alpha`, so you'd do:

```
[myButton setAlpha:0.42];
```

Comment: There's also `myButton.opaque`, inherited from `UIView`, which may be what OP was thinking of, but probably won't have the (implied) desired effect.

Comment: @Josh oh good point! I forgot about that one; I almost never use it.

Comment: myButton.alpha = some_value_between_0_1;

Answer (score 10):

setAlpha doesn't work in In swift:

```
photoButton.alpha = 0.3
```